# Only some plugins not working on wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

Some plugins not working on my theme.
I've tried deactivating all the plugins and etc. but still same issue.

How can I check what's problem? because these plugins are working with all other themes without problem.

Take example mapplic plugin: 
in admin panel everything works fine, but in frontend nothing appears.
See link: http://wbc.ge/events/

Comment: there should be some conflict between these plugins try to find out and with the detail you have given It hard to identify  the problem.

Comment: No plugin conflict, because I tried deactivating all plugins but mapplic... It may has problem with theme but how can I find it?

Comment: I guess this is blog page , so better check the archive.php template the loop has some problem I guess.

Comment: global.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

I get this debugg message...

Comment: if it is not due to $, you can consider it is not getting some value, I had got this type of error during a woo-commerce plugin development, you have to find out if you are not saving some setting or not giving some value   like that .

Comment: global.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined I get this debugg message...